# What do you name this behaviour in scala

Tags: scala

is there any name for the following behavior in scala? and what could be the reason for performing such action.

I have seen that from some sample project in github,I have defined a case class **Book**, then created an instance of that class and assigned it to some new Book Object, this results in copying all instance variables.

```
scala> case class Book(title: String, author: String)
class Book

scala> val b1 = Book("testTitle","testAuthor")
val b1: Book = Book(testTitle,testAuthor)

scala> val Book(var1,var2) = b1
val var1: String = testTitle
val var2: String = testAuthor
```

Comment: This is called extractor and done via Companion object's `unapply` method of a case.  Please read more [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html)

Comment: Note that this way of doing pattern matching is not that common for multiple reasons. The biggest one is that it doesn't warn if the extraction becomes non-exhaustive. As such, tuples is the only thing which with I have seen this being used a lot.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Scala 2 will warn on a non-exhaustive match if you enable `-Xlint`, which everyone should always use. Scala 3 warns by default. I don't think it's necessary to teach people to avoid this kind of matching.

Comment: @SethTisue are you sure about that? https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/ezFFgvRDTBG0Qj4REKiRFw - Although, it seems using the `-Xlint` option does make it warn in **Scala 2**, I guess by the time I started using **sbt-tpolecat** I was already _"afraid"_ of using this syntax.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I should have said that on Scala 3 it warns under `-source:future`. you are right, 3.1 does not warn by default, though a future version will